# How to make a 3,4 level array with PHP for an expandable tree?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand how to make a simple multidimensional array to use it to make an expendable tree. There need to be some childs/parents there.

Comment: Have a look at [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This includes a specific example of what you are trying to achieve, and ideally, examples of what you have tried to date. A good quality question will allow us to give good quality answers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get what you want, but here is how to make a multidimensional array:

```
$array = array(
    array(1,4,3,2),
    array("These are all strings","I'm a string","Me too!"),
    //Those two were just 2-dimensional, here is 3-dimensional:
    array(array("This","is","3-dimensional"),"2-dimensional")
);
```